# spring autowiring not able to hit my DAO class method

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

not able to hit my DAO class. below is my application files

```
    @Controller
    public class HelloWorldController1 {
        @Autowired
        EmpServiceIntf empService;

        public EmpServiceIntf getEmpService() {
            return empService;
        }

         public myMethod(){
            List<Employee> empList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
            empList = empService.getAllemp(abc,pqr);
          }


    --------------------my interface class-----------------

    public interface EmpServiceIntf {
    List<Employee> getAllemp(String abc, String pqr);
    }

    -------------my implementation class----------------

    public class EmpServiceImpl implements EmpServiceIntf {
    private EmpServiceDAO empDAO = new EmpServiceDAO ();
        public List<Employee> getAllemp(String abc, String pqr) {
            return empDAO.getAllemp(abc, pqr);
        }
    }

------------------------applicationContext.xml------------------------
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"   
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

<!-- Activates various annotations to be detected in bean classes-->
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="org.nea.rest.unsr" />
<context:component-scan base-package="org.nea.spring.services.implementations.Uniserv" />
<context:component-scan base-package="org.nea.spring.services.interfaces.uniservs" />


<bean id="uniservService"  class="org.nea.spring.services.implementations.Uniserv.UniservServiceJPAImpl" />


    <!--bean class="org.nea.rest.unsr.HelloWorldController1">
        <property name="uniservService" ref="uniservService"></property>
    </bean-->

<!-- Configures the annotation-driven Spring MVC Controller programming model.
Note that, with Spring 3.0, this tag works in Servlet MVC only! -->
<mvc:annotation-driven />

</beans>
----------------------------------
```

now my problem is; with the above configurations when i hit myMethod() then it goes upto my EmpServiceImpl class method and comes back to my HelloWorldController1 class back.but it did not hit my EmpServiceDAO method.can anyone help me in what to add n where so that it hit my EmpServiceDAO getAllemp method

Comment: You'll have to explain what you mean by "hit". Are you getting an exception? Unexpected results? Explain what you're expecting and what's happening instead.

Comment: Hi Ryan.hit means when i call myMethod using restfull service url .no i am not getting any exception .only it does not went to my DAO class

Comment: What proof do you have that your DAO isn't being called?

Answer (score 1):

This is just skeleton example from "Controller" to "DaoImpl".

`@Controller` - For your controller 
`@Service` - For Your Service
`@Repository` - For your Dao

```
@Controller
class YourController {
   @Autowire
   private YourService yourService;

   public String yourControllerMethod() {
       yourService.serviceMethod();
   }
}

interface YourService {
   void serviceMethod();
}

@Service
class YourServiceImpl implements YourService {
   @Autowire
   private YourDao yourDao;

   void serviceMethod(){
      yourDao.daoMethod();
   }
}

interface YourDao {
    void daoMethod();
}

@Repository
class YourDaoImpl implements YourDao {
    void daoMethod() {
    }
}
```

and in your "spring-mvc.xml" 
   `<mvc:annotation-driven />`

```
and
```

`<context:component-scan base-package="com.yourcompany.example" />`

```
to drive @Controller, @Service and @Repository annotations.
```